# What $\bigwedge_{k=1}^{+\infty}$ symbol means?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, notation

In an Uncertainty Theory text book I found this symbol: $\bigwedge_{k=1}^{+\infty}$

I knew $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}$ is a sum and $\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}$ is a product, but I have never seen before $\bigwedge_{k=1}^{+\infty}$

This operator was applied to a sequence of real numbers between 0 and 1. Hope this give additional context.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Probably related to exterior algebra https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

Comment: Possibly the antisymmetric tensor product

Comment: And probably $\bigwedge_{k=1}^\infty$ instead of $\Lambda_{n=1}^\infty$

Comment: As Hagen von Eitzen points out, the simbol is printed that way, more than a capital Lambda. No sure what letter it is and how to write it in TeX

Comment: I would guess that $\bigwedge$ is being used in the sense of infimum here.

Comment: In Tao's book *Topics in Random Matrix Theory*, he uses this notation to denote the intersection/and operator of events.

Comment: @Alnair Zhen Lin is probably right if your context really is a sequence of real numbers, but why don't you supply an actual context?  I.e. how is this symbol used in a sentence?

Comment: It is also possible to mean the meet of a collection of elements in a lattice.  [wiki:Join and Meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet)

Comment: @Alnair You can use Detexify to find how to typeset certain symbols in TeX by just drawing them (see the link) http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html.

Comment: Thanks @alberto-debernardi. Nice to know. I actually looked at HTML code of this current page.

Comment: This symbol along simply means "and", or "combine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the Zhen Lin comment and the Wikipedia description of [Uncertainty Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_theory), seems $\bigwedge$ means infimum.

In Wikipedia the (axiom 5 there) uses the operator $\min$ while the [Unceratainty Theory book](http://orsc.edu.cn/liu/ut.pdf) (PDF, axiom 4, pag.18 there) uses $\bigwedge$.